# Wildfly 27 : Cluster not work when we have multiple servergroups

Tags: wildfly, cluster-computing, wildfly-27

Trying to configure wildfly 27 in domain and in clustered environment.

1. 2 RHEL Servers and installed wildfly on both. (No HTTPD nothing)
2. Done required settings on Primary & Secondary
3. Created a full-ha servergroup named Batch and created 2 servers' batch-01 and batch-02 which is pointed to each other. After starting servergroup it is getting connected to each other and load balancing is working too.
4. Now i create a new servergroup named as api and create 2 servers api-01 and api-02.
5. When i start api then i find that it starts connecting to batch-01 and batch-02 and api-02 and similar in api-02. Which should not happen, and it should connect to api-02 only.

Following is log output:

```
2023-08-17 12:25:28,501 INFO  [org.infinispan.LIFECYCLE] (thread-25,ejb,BKAP006:batch-01) [Context=default] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [BKAP006:api-01, BKAP007:api-02, BKAP006:batch-01, BKAP007:batch-02], topology id 35
```

[image]

[image]

[image]
Any suggestion what can be corrected here?